# How to create UserControl which support other element inside it in XAML code

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, user-controls

I like to insert other `FrameworkElements` inside my `UserControl` but if I do so in XAML code the control doesn't work correctly. (I need to make like a `Panel/Grid` type `control`). In other words it lost its `contents`. How to solve this problem? I've found some examples but those one doesn't works in UWP. I want to keep following example very simple to show what I mean and need.

XAML

```
<!--THE CONTROL-->
<local:TestControl Width="300" Height="300">
    <!--LIKE TO ADD THIS ONE INSIDE THE CONTROL-->
    <TextBlock Text="Some Text"></TextBlock>
</local:TestControl>
```

XAML FOR CONTROL

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyApp.TestControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"

    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid Background="DarkGray" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10"></Grid>
</UserControl>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public sealed partial class TestControl : UserControl
    {
        public TestControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By overriding Content property

Comment: How to do that? (Overridding Content)

Comment: `public override  UIElement Content { get { /*... right code fx redirect to other control content ...*/ } set { /*... same strory as with getter ... too broad for SO ..*/ } }` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `UserControl` with a templated control.

1. Create a class called `TestControl` that inherits from `ContentControl`:

   ```
   public sealed class TestControl : ContentControl
   {
       public TestControl() => DefaultStyleKey = typeof(TestControl);
   }
   ```
2. Create a `themes` folder in your project and add a `ResourceDictinonary` called `generic.xaml` to this folder. The `themes/generic.xaml` name is important for the framework to be able to find it. In this file, you define a template for your control:

   ```
   <Style TargetType="local:TestControl">
       <Setter Property="Template">
           <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:TestControl">
                   <Grid Background="DarkGray" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10">
                       <ContentPresenter />
                   </Grid>
               </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
   </Style>
   ```
3. Create an instance of your control like before:

   ```
   <local:TestControl Width="300" Height="300">
       <!--LIKE TO ADD THIS ONE INSIDE THE CONTROL-->
       <TextBlock Text="Some Text"></TextBlock>
   </local:TestControl>
   ```

The `TextBlock` will end up where the `ContentPresenter` element is in the `ControlTemplate`.

Please refer to @Jerry Nixon's [MSDN Magazine article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/magazine/mt833441) for more information about how to create custom controls.

Comment: Great! I appreciate lot of this answer. Clear and effective!